# How to make Class name bold in plant UML

Tags: class-diagram, plantuml

It is possible to style the class name in PlantUML to italic by making the class abstract. Is there a way to style the class name so that it is **bold** as in the example class below?

[image: Bold class name]

Answer (score 4):

you can put the name of the class between "** and **".

Example:

```
@startuml

class **House** {

}

@enduml
```

Comment: Excellent.  But is there a way to get this systematically, i.e. using `skinparam` ?

Answer (score 2):

There is work now to support styles (check the PlantUML Q&A forum for more info).

```
@startuml
<style>
classDiagram {
  class {
      ' attributes and methods
      FontColor blue
      BackgroundColor yellow
      ' class name
      header {
        FontSize 20
        FontColor violet
        FontStyle bold
      }
  }
}
</style>

hide circle

class User {
  name : String
  id : integer
  toString() : String
}

@enduml
```

[image]